# How to tie WCF webservice method to objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, webforms

I have researched this but can't find a solution to my problem. 
 I have 2 projects in my solution.

1. one that holds my webpages
2. and another that holds my WCF webservice.

This webservice has methods that query a SQL Server database and return the rows back in a dataset.  
I am getting this `dataset` back to the front end and am binding them directly to a `GridView`.  I have read that not doing this and binding the `GridView` to an `objectdatasource(ods)` makes life a lot easier.
I am try to do this. I am setting the TypeName of the ods to the class name of the Webservice.  I am setting the selectmethod of the ods to the method of the web service I want to call.

I keep getting the following error `The type specified in the TypeName property of ObjectDataSource could not be found.`  I tried doing `Namespace.webservice` class name for the TypeName but I get the same error.

I am out of ideas.  Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a class in your web pages project that calls the web service.  Use this class as your objectdatasource.

Comment: There is already supposed to be a proxy class created automatically that does this right?  Since I have a service reference in my web project that points to the web service, I should already have this class.  I don't know where this class is or what it is called.  Can you tell me where to find it?  Do you have any links to articles that can show me how to do this?  Is what I am asking a fairly common thing to do?  Thanks.